# Where to find the knime node source code

Tags: eclipse, knime

I searched around the knime developer site, everyone who tried to explain how to get the source code of the node explains in a ambiguous way.

Things are not clear in their website.

So anyone please give a explicit description on how exactly one can fetch the source code from the Knime SDK? please

Comment: https://tech.knime.org/forum/knime-developers/source-code-of-the-existing-nodes#comment-47455

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following KNIME's recent announcement of venture capital funding, they have now made their [code available on Github](https://github.com/knime/knime-core).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to add dependencies to the `plugin.xml` file in a new project, and then in the package explorer view browse the plugin-dependencies for the relevant jar file.  For the 'base' nodes within KNIME(e.g. the File Readers, row/column manipulators), you need `org.knime.base`, for the datatypes, `org.knime.core`.  Most of the other KNIME-supplied plugins have IDs starting `org.knime.*`

Also, if you create a new java class and import a KNIME class then you can Ctrl+click in it's class name in the java editor to show the source directly.

There are also some instructions at - https://tech.knime.org/forum/knime-developers/source-code-of-the-existing-nodes#comment-47455 It's worth noting that you even need the SDK to do this - you can do it with a regular KNIME install. I guess it depends exactly what you are wanting to do with the source

Comment: Hi @SteveR, thanks for providing these infos, but these are no better than what I found from the `knime dev` site. But I already found something and posted it on 'knime dev'. Could you please copy the link I pasted in the comment below the question here, So I can vote you and lead the followers a explicit way to get the source code.

Comment: This is the link - https://tech.knime.org/forum/knime-developers/source-code-of-the-existing-nodes#comment-47455 I dont think tha tyou even need the SDK to do this - you can do it with a regular KNIME install.  I guess it depends exactly what you are wanting to do with the source

Comment: yes, @SteveR, I agree with you. But at least the stackoverflow is aiming at helping people finding the answer to the similar questions. I can't upvote you if you copy the link to the comment. you can include the link in your answer. Sorry for the late response, we had a holiday recently.